# Triangle mesh in Metal

Tags: swift, mesh, metal, triangulation

I'm trying to create triangle 2D mesh using SwiftUI & Metal. I have lists of vertices[929 items] and indices[1750 items] to draw a mesh. I have used method .drawIndexedPrimitives, but it isn't correct for this purpose. I think this problem should be solved by using MTKMesh, but I don't know how to apply this to 2D mesh with lists of vertices and indices. Please suggest/give some ideas to solve this problem

The code of Renderer Class below

```
import Foundation
import MetalKit


class Renderer: NSObject, MTKViewDelegate {
    
    var parent: MetalViewComponent
    var metalDevice: MTLDevice!
    var metalCommandQueue: MTLCommandQueue!
    let pipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState
    let vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer?
//    let mesh = MTKMesh(mesh: <#T##MDLMesh#>, device: <#T##MTLDevice#>)
    
    let indexBuffer: MTLBuffer?
    
    init(_ parent: MetalViewComponent) {
        self.parent = parent
        if let metalDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() {
            self.metalDevice = metalDevice
        }
        self.metalCommandQueue = metalDevice.makeCommandQueue()
        
        
        let pipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
        let library = metalDevice.makeDefaultLibrary()
        pipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: "vertexShader")
        pipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: "fragmentShader")
        pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
        
        do {
            try pipelineState = metalDevice.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: pipelineDescriptor)

        } catch {
            fatalError()
        }
           
        
        let vertices = [Vertex(position: [-3.49195e-17, -0.570297], color: [0, 1, 1, 1]),
                        Vertex(position: [-0.245024, -0.578218], color: [0, 1, 1, 1]),
                        Vertex(position: [-0.529488, -0.52307], color: [0, 1, 1, 1]),...

        let indices: [UInt32] = [470,469,433,
                                 433,469,432,
                                 470,433,434,
                                 506,469,507,
                                 469,470,507, // from 1 to 928
vertexBuffer = metalDevice.makeBuffer(bytes: vertices, length: vertices.count * MemoryLayout<Vertex>.stride, options: [])!
        indexBuffer = metalDevice.makeBuffer(bytes: indices, length: indices.count * MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size, options: [])
        super.init()
        print("Число вертексов: \(vertices.count)")
    }
func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) {
        
    }
    
    func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        guard let drawable = view.currentDrawable else {
            return
        }
        
                               
        
        let commandBuffer = metalCommandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()
        let renderPassDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor
        
        renderPassDescriptor?.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        renderPassDescriptor?.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
        renderPassDescriptor?.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .store
        
        let renderEncoder = commandBuffer?.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor!)
        
        renderEncoder?.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
        renderEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
        renderEncoder?.drawIndexedPrimitives(type: .lineStrip, indexCount: 1750, indexType: .uint32, indexBuffer: indexBuffer!, indexBufferOffset: 0)

renderEncoder?.endEncoding()
        
        commandBuffer?.present(drawable)
        commandBuffer?.commit()
    }
}//
```

This is what's drawing for now

[image]

this is what I expect

[image]

Comment: Try to make a capture and see which triangles are actually being outputted by the vertex stage. It's probably something to do with how index buffer is layed out, because the outline looks kinda similar, it's just that edges aren't in the right place.